# Не могу найти элемент xpath selenium facebook "Введите сообщение"

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, facebook, xpath

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 - Элемент списка

Не могу найти элемент "Введите сообщение...".
Как решить этот вопрос? Может подскажите инструмент для поиска?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time,random
import traceback;#uotput error


text_message = "hi! how are you"

akki_url = 'https://www.facebook.com/patrycja.springer/'


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
#driver = webdriver.Firefox()


driver.get('https://www.facebook.com/')#.maximize_window()#.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.maximize_window()
#driver.manage().window().maximize();
time.sleep(10)
element = driver.find_element_by_id("email") #находим поле с email
element.send_keys("Логин")#вводим значение

element = driver.find_element_by_id("pass") #находим поле с пароля
element.send_keys("Пароль", Keys.ENTER)#вводим значение и нажимаем ентер 

time.sleep(5)
driver.get(akki_url)#open link akki
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)
driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)

t=driver.page_source
time.sleep(5)

n_kommandy = 1
proverka = 0
try:
    #element = driver.find_element_by_partial_link_text("Сообщение").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('', Keys.ESCAPE)
    element = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Сообщение').send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    time.sleep(5)


    proverka = 1
    print ('выполнил команду НАПИСАТЬ'+str(n_kommandy))
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('ошибка команда НАПИСАТЬ'+str(n_kommandy))
n_kommandy +=1

#driver.get(akki_url) #open page user






#driver.find_element_by_class_name("_1p1v")

#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1mf _1mj"]').send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)


#driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="_1mf _1mj"]/input').send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)



n_kommandy = 1
proverka = 0
#___________________1

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//span[@id='cch_f2e9bc13ce9c558' and contains(@class, '_mh6')]/div/div[contains(@class, '_5rp7')]/div[contains(@class, '_5rpb')]/div[contains(@class, 'notranslate')]/div/div/div[contains(@class, '_1mf')]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1

    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')

n_kommandy +=1
#___________________2
try:

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"/div/div/div[contains(@class, '_1mf')]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    #element = driver..click()
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________3
try:


    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//span[@id='cch_f2e9bc13ce9c558' and contains(@class, '_mh6')]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________7
try:

    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"/div/div[contains(@class, '_5rp7')]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)   
    #element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    #element = driver..click()
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"/div[contains(@class, '_5rpb')]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    #element = driver..click()
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    #element = driver..click()
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Введите сообщение...'])[1]/following::div[5]").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_id("u_0_1h").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    #element = driver..click()
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')

n_kommandy +=1
#___________________

try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div/div/div[4]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div/span/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div']").send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)="Введите сообщение..."]').send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)="Введите сообщение..."])[1]/following::div[5]').send_keys(text_message, Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""       
    #___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//span[@id='cch_f29520d9fe5eb5c' and contains(@class, '_mh6')]/div/div[contains(@class, '_5rp7')]/div[contains(@class, '_5rpb')]/div[contains(@class, 'notranslate')]/div/div/div[contains(@class, '_1mf')]").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Введите сообщение...'])[1]/following::div[5]").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"(.//*[normalize-space(text()) and normalize-space(.)='Введите сообщение...'])[1]/following::div[5]").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('выполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy))
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('ошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy))
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u'//*[@id="cch_f15b63466ee75f"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div').send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(u"//div[@class='_1mf _1mj']").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("div").send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#"""
#___________________
try:
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath().send_keys('Hi', Keys.ENTER)
    proverka = 1
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nвыполнил команду '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
except Exception as exc:
    print(exc)
    traceback.print_exc()
    print ('\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\nошибка команда '+str(n_kommandy)+'\n_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+_+\n\n')
n_kommandy +=1

#""" 


time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id("js_9c").click()#закрыть сообщение
```

Comment: Да)))) Ваш код просто "шикарен", особенно круто выглядят 20 блоков try, принты с "\n_+_+..." и XPath в 9-ом блоке try))

Comment: Я потерялся, и так и не нашёл места, где вы пытаетесь найти элемент ввода сообщения

Comment: пробовала разные варианты, каждый try начиная от n_kommandy = 1
proverka = 0
#___________________1

Comment: Дайте мне честное слово, что будете работать над форматированием вашего кода))))) Потому что сейчас это ужас))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ломал мозг несколько часов) и теперь я доволен)))))

Вкратце по шагам:

1. Делаем импорт библиотеки

   `from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains`
2. Зашли на сайт
3. Залогинились
4. У вас есть список друзей, вы нажали на иконку вашего друга и открылось окошко чата.

*теперь что делать?))*

4. Вам нужно разместить **курсор** в строке ввода, в которую текст просто так не записывается) Используем для этого `.click()`, можете использовать любой ваш XPath, но вот покороче))

   `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@data-editor]").click()`
5. После нажатия методом `.click()`, курсор помещается в область ввода текста. И теперь нам нужно ввести текст, но `send_keys()` использовать **не** с указателем на элемент, как вы пробовали, а **отдельно** как *действие* (для этого и нужна импортированная библиотека)
   `actions = ActionChains(driver)
   actions.send_keys('HI')
   actions.perform()`

Woo a la))))

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну а дальше .click() на значке отправить или нажать Enter)))))

Comment: Благодарю)) Все сработало

Comment: Можешь подсказать как ты нашел этот элемент "@data-editor"? Что мне нужно изучить для этого?

Comment: Начни изучать XPath, он очень силён в адресации по xml файлам))) К примеру `@` это указатель на атрибут в элементе (`class`, `id`, `href`, и всё остальное что есть у элемента). Обозначение `//*` дословно можно назвать как "любой элемент" - в итоге получаем. `//*[@data-editor]` - найди любой элемент у которого есть атрибут `data-editor`))

Comment: А подскажи как добавить в друзья? С помощью xpatch? Благодарю)

Comment: @Юленька Смотря какую кнопку ты хочешь найти)) Есть блок рекомендаций по центру, есть ещё справа, и есть на странице пользователя. Вот XPath на кнопку в центральном блоке рекомендаций - `//*[contains(concat(' ', @class, ' '), 'FriendRequestAdd')]` - он найдёт 20 кнопок загруженных профилей, если нужно больше, нужно листать блок с профилями для загрузки новых) Но лучше, в случае трудностей, написать новый вопрос - комментарии ограничены в форматировании.