# Как написать комментарий в инстаграме с помощью selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, instagram, комментарии

Пробовал поиск элемента через css,xpath и через id,суть не меняется но стоило попробовать.
CSS:

```py
comment_box = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "textarea.Ypffh")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", comment_box)
comment_box.clear()
comment_box.click()
time.sleep(5)
comment_box.sendKeys('text')
```

Xpath:

```
comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/span/section/main/div/div/article/div[2]/section[3]/div/form/textarea')
comment.clear()
comment.click()
comment.send_keys('text')
```

id

```py
text_area = driver.find_element_by_id('textarea')
text_area.clear()
text_area.click()
text_area.send_keys("text")
```

Появляется мигающий курсор но выводит ошибку:  'AttributeError: 'WebElement' object has no attribute 'send_Keys''
Также пробовал вместо .sendKeys использовать .send_Keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте свободный ввод текста.

То есть, если так не работает:

```
text_area.click()
text_area.send_keys("text")
```

Но курсор установить в поле для текста получилось, то:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

text_area.click()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.send_keys('HI')
actions.perform()
```

Эту проблему я решил вот [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/919234/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82-xpath-selenium-facebook-%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5/919670#919670)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys 

driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver.get("http://page_address") 

elem = driver.find_element_by_name("name") # name поля
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("text you need to send") # текст комментария
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

driver.close()
```